# Bar graph for a python dictionary with key as labels and the values as the values to be plotted without adjusting the dimesnions

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib, visualization

I have a python dictionary like this. Each key and value pairs are different in dimensions. Also it has same values repeating in the same array of values as well as in other arrays as well. For e.g., '0' can be found repeating in the same array as well as in almost all arrays.

```
pd_plot = {'MinMaxScalerLogisticRegression': [0,0,1,6,150,200], 'StandardScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2,0,50,100], 'MaxAbsScalerKNNClassifier': [23,45,56,0,0], 'MinMaxScalerGaussianNB': [43,56,76,87,35], 'MinMaxScalerKNNClassifier': [50,2,78,135,74,0,1,5,0], 'StandardScalerKNNClassifier': [1,200], 'MinMaxScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [34,35,76,87,90,98,43,32,32,4,5], 'StandardScalerLogisticRegression': [6,7,0,1,2,5], 'MaxAbsScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2]}
```

When I try to plot a bar graph using the below code.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
myList = pd_plot.items()
myList = sorted(pd_plot) 
x, y = zip(*myList) 

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-916d14b0fed0> in <module>
      2 myList = pd_plot.items()
      3 myList = sorted(pd_plot)
----> 4 x, y = zip(*myList)
      5 
      6 plt.plot(x, y)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

When I tried other approach

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = list(pd_plot.keys())
values = list(pd_plot.values())

plt.bar(range(len(pd_plot)), values, tick_label=names)
plt.show()
```

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-319c3c2e7d40> in <module>
      4 values = list(pd_plot.values())
      5 
----> 6 plt.bar(range(len(pd_plot)), values, tick_label=names)
      7 plt.show()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py in from_extents(*args)
    787         The *y*-axis increases upwards.
    788         """
--> 789         points = np.array(args, dtype=float).reshape(2, 2)
    790         return Bbox(points)
    791 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

All the solutions for this error suggests to make the dimensions same by adding zeroes. But I cannot add zeroes since I have lot of zeroes as values in all the arrays.

Any suggestion to plot a bar graph without changing the dimensions would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please clarify how should the bar plot look like?

Comment: the bar plot should have the keys in x axis and its corresponding value in y axis. even if we have duplicates values it should print over the older one